# creating javascript modules

Tags: javascript, module

I would like to know how can I create a module and manually create more instances of that module without impacting the global scope.

Right now I have something similar to this piece of code:

```
var myModule = (function(){
    ...
})();
```

`myModule` is at this point in the global scope of my app.

What can I do to encapsulate this somewhere and call a new instance of it anytime I need one?

I am looking for something similar with Require.js or Angular.

Comment: Have you looked at commonJS? Are you looking to do this client-side, server-side, or both?

Comment: I cannot add third party libraries in my project.

Comment: It isn't only for third party libraries.   

`var coolModule = ["wow", "neat", "module"];`

`module.exports = coolModule;`


Then in another file:


`var coolModule = require("coolModule");`


Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: Yes. But the result of `require` I want to be a new instance of `coolModule`

Comment: Got it. Why not make coolModule a javascript "class" and then call that constructor on module.exports? something like [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/47afa467a4609e9a9995)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myScope={};

(function(window) {

function Module(){
    console.log('new instance of Module');
};

Module.prototype.someFunction = function(){

};

window.myScope.Module = Module;

}(window));

myModule = new myScope.Module();
```

Something like this?

Comment: The code is not working. Chrome says `TypeError: Cannot set property 'Module' of undefined`